# How to add constraints in Angular matInput form fields?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and inherited code to build on.  There is an input form like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" color="accent">
   <mat-label>Customer Name</mat-label>
   <input matInput [readonly]="currentUser.userRole > 2" required maxlength="30" type="text"
      [formControl]="customerName" value={{customerName.value}}>
   <mat-error *ngIf="customerName.invalid">{{getRequiredErrorMessage()}<mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Can someone explain what all that means?  The code is failing with

> "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'userRole')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your input for the `readonly` attribute the condition if `userRole` for `currentUser` has to be greater than 2.

The object `currentUser` maybe has as `undefined` value for that particular property. Try this and see if it fixes the error

```html
<input 
   matInput 
   [readonly]="currentUser?.userRole > 2" //Optional chaining operator "?"
   required 
   maxlength="30" 
   type="text"
   [formControl]="customerName" 
   value={{customerName.value}}
>
```

Or, if you want to do something more for enabling the `readonly` property, you could attach a function to it like this:

```html
<input 
   matInput 
   [readonly]="validateReadOnly(currentUser)" 
   required 
   maxlength="30" 
   type="text"
   [formControl]="customerName" 
   value={{customerName.value}}
>
```

```js
validateReadOnly(currentUser: YourDataTypeHere): boolean {
  // ... do some other logic needed here
  return currentUser?.userRole > 2;
}
```

Comment: That did indeed remove the error.  How?  In traditional html you have "id=blah" or class="blah" and then you can access those through Javascript.  But here in Angular there is [property]="sometext".  And appears there is another form [property]="sometext" value = {{sometext.value}}.  Apparently sometext refers to an Angular variable somewhere?  Yet sometimes it is surrounded in {{sometext.value"}}.  Why are the double parenthesis needed in one case but not the other?  What does the ? do?

Comment: @user3217883 When you use double parenthesis, in Angular is called string interpolation, where you can put a variable there, or a function call, or anything, like an operation, `{{  myVariable >= 10 }}`. The other with double brackets is call property binding, you use that, when you have the value in a variable somewhere in your .ts file
Since readonly is used with propertyBinding, you were passing the variable/object `currentUser` and in this object, the property `userRole` was undefined. If my answer solved your problem, mark it as solved please. thanks

Comment: @user3217883 You can take a look at this article for example, I would suggest taking at least a basic online course for Angular https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-angular-property-binding-and-interpolation